# Qiskit not finding CPLEX

Tags: programming, qiskit

I'm trying to use the CPLEX library alongside Qiskit but keep getting the error.

```
 File "C:\Users\charl\.conda\envs\quantum\lib\site-packages\qiskit\optimization\algorithms\cplex_optimizer.py", line 58, in __init__
    raise MissingOptionalLibraryError(
qiskit.aqua.missing_optional_library_error.MissingOptionalLibraryError: "The 'CPLEX' library is required to use 'CplexOptimizer'. You can install it with 'pip install qiskit-aqua[cplex]'."
```

Now when of course run that command, I find that all these packages are already installed.

When I tried manually updating docplex, I got a warning saying the latest version was incompatible with qiskit and so I downgraded using pip to docplex 2.15.194, yet I still get the error.

What can I do to get docplex and Qiskit to talk to one another ?

I am using a windows 10 installation of qiskit in a conda environment.

Comment: Just a wild guess, if `pip install qiskit-aqua[cplex]` didn't work, have you tried `conda install qiskit-aqua[cplex]` as you said you are using a conda environment? I've never used conda personally, hence it's just a wild guess.

Comment: Hi @Rammus, I've tried that but no dice: I think pip and conda act differently in this situation. I think the only role conda has played in this is just creating the environment ! Thanks all the same !

Answer (score 1):

I am also using Qiskit in conda environment and came over this issue some weeks ago.
I had to use pip install docplex and pip install cplex in my environment.

Afterwards it worked. I should mention that I am using Linux but don`t think this matters here...

Please always be cautious when using both pip and conda in an environment as this can cause problems. This is described on [anaconda website](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment). I am using conda environment but only pip as installer.